# Confusion with parameters.yml and config_(dev|stage|prod).yml for database connections

Tags: php, database, symfony, configuration, doctrine

I understand why I should keep my database connections in the `parameters.yml` file but I also wanted to setup additional database connections as well as different hosts for dev, stage and prod environments. I thought I could do this with the `config_dev.yml`, `config_test.yml` and `config_prod.yml` in conjunction with `config.yml`, am I wrong?

In `parameters.yml` I hold the main database connection but can I move this to the config(s) instead?

Example: `config.yml`

```
# Doctrine Configuration - notice there is no host defined here
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: blah
      connections:
        blah:
          driver:   pdo_pgsql
          port:     5432
          dbname:   blah
          user:     blah_user
          password: blah_pass
          charset:  UTF8
        foo:
          driver:   pdo_pgsql
          port:     5432
          dbname:   foo
          user:     foo_user
          password: foo_pass
          charset:  UTF8
```

Example: `config_dev.yml`

```
# Doctrine Configuration - Here I define the dev hosts
doctrine:
    dbal:
      connections:
        blah:
          host: blah_dev
        foo: 
          host: foo_dev
```

Example: `config_test.yml`

```
# Doctrine Configuration - Here I define the stage or QA hosts
doctrine:
    dbal:
      connections:
        blah:
          host: blah_stage
        foo: 
          host: foo_stage
```

Example: `config_prod.yml`

```
# Doctrine Configuration - Here I define the prod hosts
doctrine:
    dbal:
      connections:
        blah:
          host: blah_prod
        foo: 
          host: foo_prod
```

Now I have also removed the settings in `parameters.yml` but Symfony / Doctrine doesn't like this. Am I missing something? How can I setup something like I have?

Now if I define the default database connection in `parameters.yml` I can connect to it and then

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: blah_prod
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: blah
    database_user: blah_user
    database_password: blah_pass
```

and in config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

But now I loose the multiple databases I need and the ability to switch from dev to stage to prod database servers.

I must be missing some additional documentation where this is being addressed, any help would be great.

I've seen the documentation for Multiple Database connections with Doctrine

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

But I would like to avoid having to add three database options like below for each dev, stage and prod server(s) in `parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: blah_dev
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: blah
    database_user: blah_user
    database_password: blah_pass
    #database_driver2: pdo_pgsql
    database_host2: blah_stage
    #database_port2: 5432
    #database_name2: blah
    #database_user2: blah_user
    #database_password2: blah_pass
    #database_driver3: pdo_pgsql
    database_host3: blah_prod
    #database_port3: 5432
    #database_name3: blah
    #database_user3: blah_user
    #database_password3: blah_pass
```

( Maybe just configure the different hosts? )

This looks ugly and a PITA, and this is just for blah database, I would have to do this for foo and any other databases I need to configure.

Answer (score 2):

If your connections are the same in each environment but only the configuration values are different, you should use the parameters-configuration-file. Define the environment variables, you need, in the parameters.yml.dist file like this:

```
# parameters.yml.dist
parameters:
    database_host_1: blah
    database_host_2: blub
    ...
```

Your config.ml may look like this:

```
# config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
...
doctrine:
    dbal:
  default_connection: blah
  connections:
    blah:
      driver:   pdo_pgsql
      port:     5432
      host:     "%database_host_1%"
      dbname:   blah
      user:     blah_user
      password: blah_pass
      charset:  UTF8
    foo:
      driver:   pdo_pgsql
      port:     5432
      host:     "%database_host_2%"
      dbname:   foo
      user:     foo_user
      password: foo_pass
      charset:  UTF8
```

If your parameters.yml is missing, you'll be ask for the database hostnames next time you call *composer update* for example.

If you would like to save all your configurations in separate files, you should add this at the beginning of your config_XXX.yml files:

```
# config_XXX.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_XXX.yml }
```

Replace XXX with your environment. Create a parameters_XXX.yml for each environment and set the configuration parameters for your hosts in there like it is in the default parameters.yml file.

```
# parameters_XXX.yml
parameters:
    database_host_1: blahInXXXEnv
    database_host_2: blubInXXXEnv
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see there a reason to use different prod and dev parameters config files. 
You can use specific `parameters.yml.dist`

- http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html

file at your PC with all defined connections.

Multiple connetions and work with them:

- http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the documentation you've suggested but it still doesn't help my situation. For the reason as to why I want this setup. 1) I have multiple database servers, 2) I have multiple environments ( dev, stage, prod, QA ) and 3) I want to easily define/configure all these so that others ( none techie teams ) don't need to or have the ability to make these changes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you just need in config.yml remove 
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }

and add in config_dev.yml and config_prod.yml 
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_dev.yml } or - { resource: parameters_prod.yml }